# Regular expression for names with national characters

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for a regular expression to validate names (using Python standard module re).

The expression should work for names with standard latin characters (a-z), space, dash, names with western european characters (æøåüöä etc.), but also Chinese, Thai, Arab etc.

All these can be considered "letters" - they are ok, but special characters such as !@#$%&*() and quotes etc. should fail.

I haven't really found something that can do this - anybody who knows how to do this?

PS: there are thousands of characters that qualify - it's not realistic to simply list them all.

Answer (score 3):

Well the question really is what do you need this for? Maybe the opposite approach might be better for you, i.e. specify which characters are *not* allowed: e.g. `[^ \t]` etc.

You should also take a look in the [manual](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) at things like `\s`, `\w` and others, combined with setting the `LOCALE`.

Comment: This is one way to go, but I fear there might be tons of such characters in unicode.

Comment: @hstr, well, that's exactly what these special characters are for. Otherwise, why don't you tell us *exactly* why they don't work for your case?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a character class which will match all the languages you want to match:
for example

```
[\p{Cyrillic}\p{Latin}]
```

will match all cyrilic and latin letters. Not sure if this is the best solution, but it works.

[Here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) is the full reference

Comment: That would be great, but it does not work in Python's re module.

Comment: @hstr but you can use Unicode Blocks described on the same page, like \u0000 through \uFFFF and they are supported by Python